# Flow JS: how to support double colon syntax?

Tags: flowtype, ecmascript-next

When I run flow on my code (plugin for atom editor - it supports all the latest ES stuff when using `use babel` directive) I get the following error:

```
 Unexpected token :

16|       ::this.openValidator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think flow supports that syntax. Maybe it will in the future.